# Scala compiler output in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: scala, android-studio

Since updating to Android Studio 3.1, I am no longer able to see the output of the Scala compiler - all I get is the following rather unhelpful stack trace. My UI layer is Kotlin, and I can see compile errors for that just fine.

I'm using

scala-sdk-2.12.3

org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.5

[image: Screenshot]